# Coming up with a function or a single graph, given its characteristics (pre-calculus)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Give an example of a function or a single graph which has the following characteristics:
>
> 1. Hole at $(3,-1)$
> 2. Domain is all real numbers except $3$
> 3. Local minimum at $(-1,-2)$
> 4. Local maximum at $(4,4)$
> 5. Absolute or global minimum at $(7,-10)$
> 6. Roots at $-10$, $1$, and $5$
> 7. End behaviors:
>
>    - Left: Horizontal asymptote at $y=6$
>    - Right: Horizontal asymptote at $y=0$
> 8. Upper bound of $6$
> 9. No other extrema

Comment: You can create a "hole" by introducing a divide-by-zero quirk into your equation. The equation $y = -\frac{x}{3}$ represents a line. The equation $$y = -\frac{x}{3}\left(\frac{x-3}{x-3}\right)$$ represents the same line except with a hole at $(3,-1)$.

Comment: @MikePierce  For this specific problem, the hole behaves as if its not part of the graph, and thats my concern. If you try graphing it you'll probably see where im stuck.

Comment: Just draw a tiny circle at (3,-1) and forget it.